# Notify Windows Explorer that a wallpaper has been changed

Tags: c, winapi, explorer

I wrote an app that changes the Windows wallpaper by registry, but I need to notify Explorer.exe so I can see the new background. I tried using `SendMessageTimeoutW`:

```
SendMessageTimeoutW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                                        0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, NULL);
```

However, it did not work. Any function I can use?

Comment: Add SPIF_SENDCHANGE to your SystemParametersInfo call

Comment: You mean using the SystemParametersInfo function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't modify the windows registry directly for this kind of settings*; the correct way to modify the wallpaper is to call the [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) API, passing `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER`, passing the path to the wallpaper in `pvParam` and `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE` in `fWinIni` (which makes the modification permanent).

Comment: But what about changing the wallpaper that has been set by a GPO? Does it work?

Comment: GPO generally just disable the UI to change stuff, a straight API call like this should work. Whether the setting is retained after a reboot (and a re-application of the GPO) is anybody's guess, but I don't think that a straight registry modification is any more resistant.

Comment: I am going to try this out and will be back to this thread. Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: Sorry, it only works on a local environment, not a domain environment because it does not modify the registry path where the desktop wallpaper is applied. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As Matteo suggested, I used the `SystemParametersInfo` function to set the wallpaper like this:

```
BOOL setDesk = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, L"C:\\MyWall.jpg", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

But It only works on a local environment, not in a domain one. I had to set the wallpaper by modifying the registry and then used the same function to just notify Windows about the change:

```
BOOL setDesk = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```